# What is a meaning word "a"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please explain the meaning of the word/letter,  **"a"** in gazette title.

> Boris Johnson risks major row with Donald Trump after allowing controversial Chinese app TikTok a London HQ.

[www.thesun.co.uk/news/12295304/boris-johnson-clashes-donald-trump-tiktok-london-hq/amp/](http://www.thesun.co.uk/news/12295304/boris-johnson-clashes-donald-trump-tiktok-london-hq/amp/)

I guess it means "have".

Comment: Yes, allowed a London space means permitted them to have one. So *a* does not mean *have a*, but the word *allowed* includes allowed to have, to do, to own.

Comment: It's being used as a simple article.  It's just that the "sentence" is hard to parse.  Johnson allowed TikTok to have a London HQ.

Comment: I kinda understand what is the meaning of the word/letter. Here word "allow" have a meaning "to let have". So "a" is an article. It is sort of one of HQ's total amount that is in London.

Comment: Understand that a "headline" is often "telegraphic" in style, with words left out.

Comment: Not so much 'one of the HQs that are in London' as 'an office in London to use as their HQ'.

Answer (score 1):

**“A” is just being used normally as an article.**

If we shave down the sentence to just the necessary words we need to answer this question, we get:

> Johnson allows TikTok a London HQ.

All this means is that TikTok is now allowed to build an HQ in London.

You could also think of this as:

> Johnson allows TikTok [to build] a London HQ.